# D2XX library continuous reading outputs one byte garbage

Tags: rs232

**

### [SOLVED]

**

I am trying to utilize the D2XX library for continuous reading of whatever the MCU is sending, and printing it on console window.

My MCU is atmega328p, which outputs UART, and the FT230XS IC is converting it to USB. I have selected the "D2XX" library on the FT230XS:

[image: D2XX]

Here is the issue: I plug the PCB on the USB port, I run the below code to show me what the MCU sends, which is just counting (1 2 3 ...) every second, and after each number, I get a 'Δ', (0x7F in hex) which is not being sent by the MCU, and cannot understand why it is there. Below a screenshot of the output of my program. 1st column, is the number of bytes read from the MCU. 2nd column is the actual bytes the MCU sent. 3rd column I print the 'Δ' character (the last character read).

[image: D2XX]

And I know the characters being sent are correct, since I can use TeraTerm (which uses COM port) to show the output:

[image: TeraTerm]

Here is my Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ftd2xx.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])

{

FT_STATUS ftStatus;
DWORD numDevs;

FT_HANDLE ftHandle;

DWORD EventDWord;
DWORD TxBytes;
DWORD RxBytes;
DWORD BytesReceived;

FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE *devInfo;
// create the device information list
ftStatus = FT_CreateDeviceInfoList(&numDevs);
if (ftStatus == FT_OK)
{
    printf("Number of devices is %d\n",numDevs);
}
if (numDevs > 0)
{
    // allocate storage for list based on numDevs
    devInfo =
    (FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE*)malloc(sizeof(FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE)*numDevs);
    // get the device information list
    ftStatus = FT_GetDeviceInfoList(devInfo,&numDevs);
    if (ftStatus == FT_OK)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numDevs; i++)
        {
            printf("Dev %d:\n",i);
            printf(" Flags=0x%x\n",devInfo[i].Flags);
            printf(" Type=0x%x\n",devInfo[i].Type);
            printf(" ID=0x%x\n",devInfo[i].ID);
            printf(" LocId=0x%x\n",devInfo[i].LocId);
            printf(" SerialNumber=%s\n",devInfo[i].SerialNumber);
            printf(" Description=%s\n",devInfo[i].Description);
            printf(" ftHandle=0x%x\n",devInfo[i].ftHandle);
        }
    }
}

//=============Open the Device===============

ftStatus = FT_Open(0,&ftHandle);
if (ftStatus == FT_OK)
{
    // FT_ClrRts OK
    printf("Open ok\n");
}

//send reset signal to MCU
ftStatus = FT_SetRts(ftHandle);
usleep(100);//100us
ftStatus = FT_ClrRts(ftHandle);

//check if Clear suceeded
if (ftStatus == FT_OK)
{
    // FT_ClrRts OK
    printf("clr ok\n");
}

ftStatus = FT_SetBaudRate(ftHandle, 1000000); // Set baud rate to 1M

if (ftStatus == FT_OK)
{
    // FT_Open OK, use ftHandle to access device
    printf("Device opened\n");
    char RxBuffer[256];//make a buffer to store input data

    while(1)
    {
//Get status: do we have bytes to read?
        FT_GetStatus(ftHandle,&RxBytes,&TxBytes,&EventDWord);

        if (RxBytes > 0)//if we have bytes to read
        {
            ftStatus = FT_Read(ftHandle,RxBuffer,RxBytes,&BytesReceived);
            printf("%d ",RxBytes);//print the nu,ber of bytes read
            RxBuffer[RxBytes] = '\0';//put an end character on the last position of the array

            if (ftStatus == FT_OK)
            {
                // FT_Read OK
                //printf("Read ok\n");
                printf("%s", (char *)RxBuffer);//print the new characters up to \0
                printf(" %X", RxBuffer[RxBytes - 1]);//print the last character read (the unwanted one)
                printf("\n");//new line

            }
        }
    }


}

FT_Close(ftHandle);
printf("device closed\n");


return 0;
}
```

The only "weird" behavior, is that after I run TeraTerm to open the Com port, and then I run my program, this bug gets fixed!. This is the output of my program after I use TeraTerm for my com port:

[image: D2XX]

This "Bug" re-appears if I re-plug the MCU on the usb port.

Comment: So it would seem fairly certain that the problem is the USB adapter. Which is very common, most RS-232 to USB adapters are utter trash. Though also ensure that you connected signal ground.

Comment: Thanks man, but solved the issue (check my answer down below). Why are they trash though? They are weird to use sometimes, but they do the job. Can you suggest any alternative? :)

Comment: Because China...? Nobody is willing to pay for quality adapters and so nobody is making them either. The best advise I can give is to buy adapters directly from someone well-known like FTDI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured this out. I was not setting the FT_SetDataCharacteristics of the usb.

Adding my USB characteristics:

```
 // Set 8 data bits, 1 stop bit and no parity
ftStatus = FT_SetDataCharacteristics(ftHandle, FT_BITS_8, FT_STOP_BITS_1,
FT_PARITY_NONE);
if (ftStatus == FT_OK)
{
    printf("FT_SetDataCharacteristics OK\n");
}
else
{
    printf("FT_SetDataCharacteristics Failed\n");
}
```

just after opening the device (FT_Open) fixed the issue. This is why it was also fixed after opening TeraTerm. TeraTerm was setting the Data characteristics, and then these were saved on that com port, for any next device that opens the com port.